# Edit model data after EF6 add

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, addition

Usually tipical EF6 add should be

```
var newStudent = new Student();
newStudent.StudentName = "Bill";
context.Students.Add(newStudent);
context.SaveChanges();
```

In my case i'm using this logic

```
var student = context.Students.Find(id);
if (student == null)
{
    student = new Student();
    context.Students.Add(student );
}
student.blabla1 = "...";
student.blabla2 = "...";
//other 20 blabla...
student.StudentName = "Bill"; // StudentName is a required field
context.SaveChanges();
```

It's a bad practise edit data model after add method on entity framework 6? With a context injected can be thrown an error on case savechanges is called on another method and my actual thread is just before the assignment of the "StudentName"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you can't do it like this ...

```
   var student = context.Students.Find(id);

   if (student == null)
    {
        student = new Student();
        ModifyBlabla(student );//call private method
        context.Students.Add(student);
    }
  else
   {
     ModifyBlabla(student );//call private method
   }

    context.SaveChanges();
```

**Method for Edit :**

```
private void ModifyBlabla(Student student)
{
   student.blabla1 = "...";
   student.blabla2 = "...";
   //other 20 blabla...
   student.StudentName = "Bill";
}
```

Comment: thats because newStudent (yes, my mistake i have renamed "newStudent" to "student") can exists, and in case of it exists i don't need to set only "StudentName" but also other 20 properties.